# I'm trying to build a web app for a class project but I don't know if I should use PHP7 Non Thread Safe or Thread Safe?

Tags: php, angular, project

I am a complete noob at actual programming, I only know python but I'd prefer not to use that to program. I would like to use PHP7+ and Typescript with Angular 2+ (I read online that these are good to use). However, I have no idea how I would connect them all. Or which version of each program to use. My web app is supposed to have 3 different types of logins, employer, employee and customer login which will all have different levels of authorisation. a bit like admin and normal. I also want graphs to be generated and questions from a database to be generated. I am honestly stuck, I've never done anything like this before but I guess everyone needs a starting point. 
Also if you there are better programs I should use please let me know. I don't really know what programs are best for this type of task

Answer (score 1):

A thread-safe (TS) version should be used if you install PHP as an Apache module, as a worker MPM (multi-processing model).
The non-thread safe (NTS) version should be used if you install PHP as a CGI binary.
Moreover, using thread-safe version here degrade the performance due to unnecessary checks for thread safety, but you wouldn't notice the time difference as it will be in microseconds, until you are running a tons of scripts simultaneously.
If you are using Servers like IIS & NGINX, then you do not need thread safe versions.